# express-handlebars helper doesnt display return value

Tags: express, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I try to register my own helper methods to express-handlebars to use it in views and partials. My goal is to create a  for a search function in my navigation partial. But I dont even get my helper working on my index view.

I tried a lot of thinks..

App.js

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const helpers = require('./public/helper/hbs-helper');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const hbs = exphbs.create({
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts'),
  partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/partials'),
  helpers: helpers
})

app.enable('trust proxy')
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  extname: '.hbs'
}))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
```

hbs-helper.js

```
module.exports = {
  sayHello: function(elem) {
    return 'hello!'
  }
}
```

index.hbs - here i tried everything, but not at the same time ;):

```
<p>{{sayHello}}</p>
<p>{{#sayHello}}</p>
<p>{{sayHello this}}</p>
```

- First one gives me an empty p-tag
- Second one says "Error: Parse error on line ..."
- Third one says "Error: Missing helper: "sayHello""

It doesnt matter if put "elem" to the function definition, it still doesnt work.

I also tried to implement the given example from https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars with foo and bar helper (not importing them with require(), I really did the same), but it doesnt work for me. It never displays any of the return values.

Do u guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer from Vivasaayi worked for me!
[can't register handlebar helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209282/cant-register-handlebar-helpers)
Just use following code

helpers.js

```
let register = function(Handlebars) {
let helpers = {
sayHello: function(elem) {
  return 'hello!'
  }
};
if (Handlebars && typeof Handlebars.registerHelper === "function") {
  for (let prop in helpers) {
    Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
  }
} else {
  return helpers;
}
};
module.exports.register = register;
```

app.js

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const hbs = exphbs.create({
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts'),
  partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/partials')
})
require("./pathto/helper.js").register(hbs.handlebars);
```